# How to Handle Multiple Dynamic Forms in a Single Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've got a basic html form that a user fills out but then i've got an option for them to be able to add whether or not a client purchased a property. When they click the add property button it appends the below form with jQuery into the original form. The user can choose to add more than one property.

What is the best way to handle posting this?

```
    <div id="ProperySection" class="Property">
                                            <h5>Sales Info</h5>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    <label for="SaleType">Sale Type</label>
                                                    <select class="form-control">
                                                    <option>SMSF</option>
                                                    <option>Direct Sale</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    <label for="SaleDate">Sale Date</label>
                                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="SaleDate" required>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    <label for="PropertyAddress">Property Address</label>
                                                    <input id="PropertyAddress" class="form-control" required>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="SaleOffice">Office</label>
                                                    <input id="SaleOffice" class="form-control" required>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="PropertySpecialist">Property Investment Specialist</label>
                                                    <input id="PropertySpecialist" class="form-control" required>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                                    <label for="ClientManager">Client Manager</label>
                                                    <input id="ClientManager" class="form-control" required>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                                    <label for="LeadSource">Lead Source</label>
                                                    <input id="LeadSource" class="form-control" required>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                                    <label for="LandVendor">Land Vendor</label>
                                                    <input id="LandVendor" class="form-control" required>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                                    <label for="Builder">Builder</label>
                                                    <input id="Builder" class="form-control" required>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: use a `class` to label the "property" inputs. So you can have multiples.  Then in your jQuery use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to roll through the classes, get teh values and store them in an `array` that you will pass to your processing page .

Comment: One thing to fix: If you are repeating the above code, you will end up with multiple elements with the same `id`. That's no good. `id`s must be unique.

Comment: Yeah I figured and that's the problem i'm facing at the moment. How would you keep them unique when you don't know how many of the forms could be added?

Comment: *"`id` must be unique"*   Well, only for those tags that have `id`'s.